# How do parental-control app do web filtering and site blocking 

Tags: web, filter

I just wonder how does the parental-control sites do problematically the web filtering and the URL blocking in their applications?

I ask because I need to build something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent control applications are web proxies that look for particular strings in the web address.  If the proxy encounters one of the strings on the "naughty" list, access to the web page is blocked.

Blocked means that the web proxy sends its own HTML page, rather than the "naughty" web page.

Some parent control applications have a white list of web pages, rather than trying to black list the "naughty" web pages.  A white list means that only the web pages in the list will be shown, and all other web pages will be blocked.

The trick is making it easy for the parents to control the "naughty" list, without the kids being able to turn the proxy off.

Comment: i meant not the one in the server side , but the ones that are installed in the client side. for example:
http://www.cyberpatrol.com/products.asp  or http://www.netnanny.com/

Comment: Everything I said applies to an application installed on a client computer.  It's still a web proxy.  You also have to create a way to push updated "naughty" lists to the clients.

Comment: Ok thanks , do you know about freeware open source web proxys i can download?

Comment: Thanks , do you know maybe something written in c/c++

Comment: ok i downloaded net nanny and there is no proxy ,they using 
they dont configure the browsers to use proxy , they also don't   install winpcap or something . so the question remains the same   ,how they do that ?